# Objective-c Regex error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

I have this String:

```
{{nat fs g player|no=1|pos=GK|name=[[Hugo Lloris]]|age={{Birth date and age|1986|12|26|df=y}}|caps=73|goals=0|club=[[Tottenham Hotspur F.C.|Tottenham Hotspur]]|clubnat=ENG}}
```

and i want to get the data from this string so i build regex with:

https://regex101.com/r/jA1zS4/1

But when i run this code in the my project i get error:

```
NSString *string = @"{{nat fs g player|no=1|pos=GK|name=[[Hugo Lloris]]|age={{Birth date and age|1986|12|26|df=y}}|caps=73|goals=0|club=[[Tottenham Hotspur F.C.|Tottenham Hotspur]]|clubnat=ENG}}";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"{{nat fs g player\\|no=(.*)\\|pos=(.*?)\\|name=\[\[(.*?)\\]\\]\\|age=\{\{Birth date and age\\|(.*?)\\|(.*?)\\|(.*?)\\|df=y\\}\\}\\|caps=(.*?)\\|goals=(.*?)\\|club=\[\[(.*?)\\|(.*)"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];


Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “{{nat fs g player\|no=(.*)\|pos=(.*?)\|name=[[(.*?)\]\]\|age={{Birth date and age\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|df=y\}\}\|caps=(.*?)\|goals=(.*?)\|club=[[(.*?)\|(.*)” is invalid." UserInfo={NSInvalidValue={{nat fs g player\|no=(.*)\|pos=(.*?)\|name=[[(.*?)\]\]\|age={{Birth date and age\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|df=y\}\}\|caps=(.*?)\|goals=(.*?)\|club=[[(.*?)\|(.*)}
```

Comment: You failed to escape the square brackets properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a bit different regex: I'd replace all `.*?` with `[^|]*` for better performance:

```
\{\{nat fs g player\|no=([^|]*)\|pos=([^|]*)\|name=\[\[([^|]*)\]\]\|age=\{\{Birth date and age\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|df=y}}\|caps=([^|]*)\|goals=([^|]*)\|club=\[\[([^|]*)\|(.*)
```

And in Objective-C, you need to escape all `|`, `[`, `]`, `{` and `}`:

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\{\\{nat fs g player\\|no=([^|]*)\\|pos=([^|]*)\\|name=\\[\\[([^|]*)\\]\\]\\|age=\\{\\{Birth date and age\\|([^|]*)\\|([^|]*)\\|([^|]*)\\|df=y\\}\\}\\|caps=([^|]*)\\|goals=([^|]*)\\|club=\\[\\[([^|]*)\\|(.*)";
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/qHmCIk) proving there is a match.